# How remove javascript based default url, page count and date in window.print()?

Tags: javascript

```
  [From the Output have to remove page url, page count from header and footer][1]
      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW9Yt.jpg
```

> How remove javascript based default url, page count and date in window.print()?
>   browser print setup not use only code based remove

Comment: You can't, the header and the footer are user preferences in a browser, JS can't access user preferences.

Comment: Well, you could generate a PDF.

Comment: Those aren't JavaScript based. They are just default print settings.